# Angular.js with jQuery Sparklines

Tags: jquery-plugins, angularjs, sparklines

Noob question:  I'm trying out the new Angular.js framework but can't seem to get my sparklines to display on my partials.  The arrays I want graphed do display in text.

It seems to be a problem with when the string loads on the page and when Sparklines are called.  I'm calling the jQuery sparklines in the `<head>`.

How do I get these to display in an ng-repeat?

Answer (score 3):

Check out the JQuery wrapper from the AngularUI project:

https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/blob/master/modules/directives/jq/jq.js

The issue is with plugins that change the DOM without alerting AngularJS to the change.

Comment: Thank you! Is there documentation for implementing this?